# How do I get TextMate style quotes in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

In textmate, when there's a current selection, I hit the " key and the selection gets surrounded by quotes. The same thing happens with other balanced characters like (, {, [ and '.

Am I missing something obvious in Emacs configuration that would enable similar behaviour when using transient mark mode, or do I need to break out elisp and write something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try http://autopair.googlecode.com

Comment: I'll second autopair. I've been using it for a while now and it's near perfect replacement. Yasnippet by the same guy is also a perfect replacement for Textmate snippets.

Comment: This answer also courtesy of "the same guy".  :)

Answer (score 6):

wrap-region.el from [this guy's blog post](http://sami.samhuri.net/2007/6/23/emacs-for-textmate-junkies) will do what you're looking for.

[Paredit](http://mumble.net/~campbell/emacs/paredit.el) will complete the TextMate-style quoting. When you type one part of a matched pair (quotes, brackets, parentheses, etc), the second will be inserted and the insertion point is moved between them, much like TextMate.

Comment: Mmm... wrap region's nice. Now, if I can just get it to work out how to restore the selection after doing the wrap.

Comment: The skeleton-pair mechanism mentioned in the post preamble is quite general and is built-in to emacs -- no need to fetch wrap-region for new emacs installs or worry about wrap-region's compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out these older, very similar, questions:

[Automatically closing braces in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023770/automatically-closing-braces-in-emacs/1024531#1024531)

[Emacs typeover skeleton-pair-insert-maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848647/emacs-typeover-skeleton-pair-insert-maybe/849218#849218)

Although the correct answer is Joao's above;  I'm about to go and change my answer to those questions, to point to autopair.