# Emacs typeover skeleton-pair-insert-maybe

Tags: c#, java, emacs

In Eclipse, editing Java code, if I type an open-paren, I get a pair of parens.  If I then "type through" the second paren, it does not insert an additional paren.  How do I get that in emacs?

The Eclipse editor is smart enough to know, when I type the close-paren, that I am just finishing what I started. The cursor advances past the close paren.  If I then type a semicolon, same thing: it just overwrites past the semicolon, and I don't get two of them.

In emacs, in java-mode, or csharp-mode if I bind open-paren to skeleton-pair-insert-maybe, I get an open-close paren pair, which is good.  But then if I "type through" the close paren, I get two close-parens.

Is there a way to teach emacs to not insert the close paren after an immediately preceding skeleton-pair-insert-maybe?   And if that is possible, what about some similar intelligence to avoid doubling the semicolon?

I'm asking about parens, but the same applies to double-quotes, curly braces, square brackets, etc.  Anything inserted with skeleton-pair-insert-maybe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This post](http://cmarcelo.wordpress.com/2008/04/26/a-little-emacs-experiment/) shows how to do what you want.  As a bonus it also shows how to set it up so that if you immediately backspace after the opening char, it will also delete the closing char after the cursor.

Update:

Since I posted this answer, I've discovered [Autopair](http://code.google.com/p/autopair/) which is a pretty much perfect system for this use case.  I've been using it a lot and loving it.

Comment: simple, easy.  Just what I wanted.

Comment: autopair = perfect.  just what i wanted too.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize what I did, I looked at this post, and took what I wanted out of it.  What I ended up with was simpler, because I didn't have the additional requirements he had.

I used these two new definitions:

```
(defvar cheeso-skeleton-pair-alist
  '((?\) . ?\()
    (?\] . ?\[)
    (?" . ?")))


(defun cheeso-skeleton-pair-end (arg)
  "Skip the char if it is an ending, otherwise insert it."
  (interactive "*p")
  (let ((char last-command-char))
    (if (and (assq char cheeso-skeleton-pair-alist)
             (eq char (following-char)))
        (forward-char)
      (self-insert-command (prefix-numeric-value arg)))))
```

And then in my java-mode-hook, I bound the close-paren and close-bracket this way:

```
(local-set-key (kbd ")") 'cheeso-skeleton-pair-end)
(local-set-key (kbd "]") 'cheeso-skeleton-pair-end)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use paredit-mode, which does this and a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

[ParEdit](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ParEdit) sounds like it would handle the parenthesis part of your need, with the caveat that it was designed for Common Lisp and Scheme. [Steve Yegge mentions JDEE for emacs Java development](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsteve.yegge.googlepages.com%2Fmy-dot-emacs-file&ei=CGIISquGHZTAM5Hd6aID&usg=AFQjCNEP7WazHypzy4GtNKEijGulheVprA), but I can't speak for that from personal experience, and I couldn't find any documentation on it talking about structured editing.