# Textmate-like smart quotes/parentheses as a script/service

Tags: macos, textmate

so Textmate has this great feature of auto-closing ( { [ " ' signs and putting the caret between them,

e.g. `type [ --> get []`

and also on selected text, if you press any of these keys, it will wrap the text in a pair of them. e.g.

```
*some selected text* , hit ( --> (*some selected text*)
```

how would i go about writing a script (Applescript?) which replicates this feature, so that it is usable system-wide?

see also here: 
[How do I get TextMate style quotes in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72732/how-do-i-get-textmate-style-quotes-in-emacs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a Automator service like the following:
[alt text http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/176/balancesquarebracketsse.png](http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/176/balancesquarebracketsse.png)